# Subtract a number from array starting backwards from tail ([1,2,3] - 4 = [1,1,0])

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I want to subtract a number "n" starting from the last index, some examples:

```
[1,2,3,4] - 2 = [1,2,3,2]
[1,2,3,4,0,0] - 3 = [1,2,3,1,0,0]
[1,2,3,4,0] - 6 = [1,2,1,0,0]
```

The subtracting number will never be greater than the sum of array values.

Currently I'm using a solution for fixed array sizes with a trivial loop and subtraction. How would I approach this for a dynamic size? What PHP methods will make this easier?

Comment: Please follow the How to Ask guidelines (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your chances of having an adequate answer. Specifically, post what you attempted and any specific failures you faced.

Comment: [`sizeof()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) alias [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)-function will do the trick

Comment: @Vera Wang It would be nice if you could provide the code of your static approach with the fixed array size. So the community can better understand what you are searching for. Currently they think the question is to broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've prepared a small sample code which should work:

```
$arr1 = array( 1,2,3,4); //-2
$arr2 = array( 1,2,3,4,0,0); //-3
$arr3 = array( 1,2,3,4,0,); //-6


array_subtract( $arr1, 2 );
array_subtract( $arr2, 3 );
array_subtract( $arr3, 6 );

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
print_r($arr3);

//heres a handy function which requires the array and the subtraction value as input 
function array_subtract( &$array, $sub ) { 
    $size = sizeof( $array ) - 1;

    for( $i = $size; $i >= 0; $i-- ) :
        if ($sub > 0 ) :
            if ( $array[$i] > $sub ) :
                $array[$i] -= $sub;
                $sub = 0;
            else : 
                $sub -= $array[$i];
                $array[$i] -= $array[$i];
            endif;
        else :
            break;
        endif;
    endfor;    
}
```

The `print_r` output looks like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```